# Magento 2: How to show price in decimal (Instead rounding) in cart items & cart summary?

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.4, rounding

[image: subtotal roundup]

**In above image showing product price** `KWD0.245` **but Summary section Subtotal showing** `KWD0.250 (Automatic roundup)` **, how to avoid subtotal automatic roundup. I want to show subtotal as** `KWD0.245`.

**Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

you can use plugin for that

**Create di.xml at app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

**then here you can override this core class** `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
        <plugin name="CustomQuote" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Quote" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

then you can create your plugin class and override the magento method responsible for collecting total amount

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Quote
{
    public function beforeCollectTotals() {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```